# Query Exception when select on entity where ForeignKey is NULL in a ManyToMany Doctrine queryBuilder()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, query-builder, dql

In my Symfony project, I have two entities `Product.php` and `Configuration.php`.

It's a `ManyToMany` relation.

This is relation in `Product.php`:

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Configuration", inversedBy="products")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_configuration",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id", nullable=true)},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="configuration_id", referencedColumnName="configuration_id")}
 * )
 **/
protected $configurations;
```

and this is `Configuration.php`:

```
/**
 * Describes the products using $this configuration
 *
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", mappedBy="configurations")
 **/
protected $products;
```

In a page, I need to recover **products** which **do not** have some **configurations**, e-g where **FK configurations** is **NULL**.

So I create this **queryBuilder()/dql** in `Productrepository.php` :

```
public function getProductForCurrentWorkType($slug)
  {
    // First we get all the product even with configurations
    $selectProduct = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $selectProduct
      ->select('p, wt, c')
      ->from('MyBundle:Product', 'p')
      ->join('p.workType', 'wt', 'WITH', 'wt.id = p.workType')
      ->join('p.configurations', 'c')
      ->where('wt.slug = :slug')
      ->setParameters(array('slug' => $slug));

    // Then we apply a filter where configurations is null for product.
    // We get all products where product.id  are not in ids of the first request
    $nullConfiguration = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $nullConfiguration
      ->select('pr.id')
      ->from('MyBundle:Product', 'pr')
      ->where($nullConfiguration->expr()->notIn('pr.id', $selectProduct->getDQL()));

    return $nullConfiguration->getQuery()->getResult();
  }
```

The fist Step works well if I return only the first query e-g `$selectProduct`. It returns on only the product which have a configuration for `$slug`.
But if I return the second query (the code below), an error occurred:

> 2/2 [Syntax Error] line 0, col 69: Error: Expected
> Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got ','
>
> 1/2 QueryException: SELECT pr FROM MyBundle:Product pr WHERE pr.id NOT
> IN(SELECT p, wt, c FROM MyBundle:Product p INNER JOIN p.workType
> wt WITH wt.id = p.workType INNER JOIN p.configurations c WHERE wt.slug
> = :slug)

How can I fix this error?

### EDIT

Another solution I tried, in my `ProductRepository.php` :

```
$selectProduct = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $selectProduct
      ->select('p, wt, c')
      ->from('MyBundle:Product', 'p')
      ->join('p.workType', 'wt', 'WITH', 'wt.id = p.workType')
      ->join('p.configurations', 'c')
      ->having('COUNT(c.id) = 0') // check if the collection is empty
      ->where('wt.slug = :slug')
      ->setParameters(array('slug' => $slug));

      return $selectProduct
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

And now my controller if it could help you:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$arrayProduct = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->getProductForCurrentWorkType($slug);

if (!$arrayProduct) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find a Product !');
}

//return statement
```

This code below returns me **Unable to find a Product !**, If I remove the if condition with the throw `$this->createNotFoundException`, the page is displaying right but no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this one :

```
$qb->select('p')
   ->from('Product','p')
   ->leftJoin('p.configurations','c')
   ->having('COUNT(c.id) = 0') // check if the collection is empty
   ->groupBy('p.id');
```

Comment: I already try this query, and it returns me no result while I have many matching records in my database

Comment: Maybe there is something else another where clause that is returning an empty result can you put what do you have tried with this one

Comment: change join with left join

Comment: I just realize that my initial query with having close is not absolutely like your suggestion, and I just try your entire answer as you write, and It works, sorry for not have tested the code like you wrote it.
You can edit your answer if you wish, but your query builder work very well. Thank you by the way.

Comment: I would like to find the solution with the closure `->notIn()` but your answer is sufficient. You save my day. You rock !